# Flutter type '_SimpleUri' is not a subtype of type 'String' error

Tags: flutter

This is my simple code

```
 try{
       final dynamic headers = await _getReqHeader();
       http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);
      print("Dres2="+res.toString());
  
      return _result(res);
    }catch(e){
      print("Dres3="+e.toString());

      return _result({});
    }
```

This code works well. But when use some url's I get type ***'_SimpleUri' is not a subtype of type 'String'*** error. In postman this url works perfectly. I could not find any information about **_SimpleUri**. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you include the part of code where you assign value to `url` variable?

Comment: You must be having a variable named '_SimpleUri' in your code, and that is getting passed to 'Uri.parse()' somehow.

Comment: As I said this particular url works perfectly in Postman

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method of the `http` package takes `Uri.https(hostUrl , apiEndpoint)` not `Uri.parse`.

The error appears because a simple URLs being passed to it. To fix this, you have to do this:

```
http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.https(host, url), headers: headers);
```

I had a similar issue and that's how I solved it.

```
static const baseUrl = "apihost.com";

Future<http.Response> _get(String url, {host = baseUrl}) async {
    final header = <String, String>{};
    return http.get(Uri.https(host, url), headers: header);
}

Future<String?> getData() async {
    final response = await _get("/endpoint");

    if (isSuccessful(response)) {
        final json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    } else {
        print('GET failed [${response.statusCode}]: 
    ${response.body}');
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I mistakenly parsed the URL twice:

1. When I passed it from the URL.

2. While making the request.

```
fetchData(url) { //Here this URL in parameter was already parsed from previous function
try {
   http.Response res = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),//Then I mistakely parsed it here again
    headers: headers,
   );
   return _result(res);
 } catch(e) {
  //e
  }
}
```